# GAS - Change Folder Permissions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've been working on a script that lists the name and folder ids of the all the folders in a specific folder in my drive. Once the list is created, I run the function to get the id and change the folder permissions to private (only specific people can view), remove editors who do not have the company domain and switches them to viewers, and then it should change the permissions for any files in the folder as well. The initial step of creating the ids works fine. Unfortunately, the updatePermissions() function only seems to infinitely loop through the first folder and I'm not sure what next steps to take to ensure that the script pulls the next folder id from the list in the spreadsheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function listSchoolFolders(){  

  var folderId = 'enter folder id here';

  var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var childFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();

  // List folders inside the folder

  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    var data = [ 
      childFolder.getName(),
      childFolder.getId()
    ];

//Write
   myspreadsheet.appendRow(data)

  }   
}



//------------------------- New Function -------------------------//


function updatePermissions() {
  var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var schoolRows = myspreadsheet.getDataRange();
  var schoolNumRows = schoolRows.getNumRows();
  var schoolValues = schoolRows.getValues();

  //Loop through List of Schools
  var row_num = schoolValues[0][2];
  while(row_num<schoolNumRows){

  //Retrieve folder id and go to folder
    var folderId = schoolValues[row_num][1];
    var folderName = schoolValues[row_num][0];
    Logger.log(folderName);
    try {
      var schoolFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    }
    catch (err){
      Logger.log(folderName + ": " + err.message);
      row_num = row_num+1;
      myspreadsheet.getRange(1,3).setValue(row_num);
      continue;
   };
 };

//Loop through folders and set permissions
  var childFolders = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFolders();
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) { 
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    var childFolderPermissions = childFolder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);

    var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      Logger.log(files.next().getName());
      var fileFolderPermissions = files.next().setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);

//check for rogue editors    
    var viewEditors = schoolFolder.getEditors();
    for (i in viewEditors) {
      var email = viewEditors[i].getEmail();
      var emailSource = email.split("@")[1]
      if (emailSource != "tester.com") {
      // add as a viewer or remove completely?
        addViewer(email)
      };
    };  
   };
 };   
    // Recursive call for any sub-folders
  getChildFolders(childFolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the logic checking for child folders. If there was no child folder, the script completed. I've added two conditional checks on each top-level folder, one for child folders and one for files. This script functions with one-level depth.

```js
  function updatePermissions() {

  // define several variables to use throughout the script
  var editors, domain, email;

  var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var schoolValues = myspreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Loop through List of folders
  // Skip row 1
  for(var i=1; i<schoolValues.length; i++) {

    //Retrieve folder id and go to folder
    var folderId = schoolValues[i][1];
    var folderName = schoolValues[i][0];
    Logger.log(folderName);

    var schoolFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    // Get the children
    var childFolders = schoolFolder.getFolders();

    // test for child folders.
    if(!childFolders.hasNext()) {

      // There is no child folder, so test for files
      if(!schoolFolder.getFiles().hasNext()) {

        // There are no files, so get the folder editors and loop
        editors = schoolFolder.getEditors();
        for(var j=0; j<editors.length; j++) {
          email = editors[j].getEmail();
          domain = editors[j].getDomain(); // easier than using a split function

          // Check the domain. Remove if no match, add as viewer if there is a match
          if(domain !== "testdomain.com") {
            schoolFolder.removeEditor(email)
          } else {
            schoolFolder.removeEditor(email).addViewer(email);
          }
        }
      } 

      // There are child folders, loop through and change permissions
    } else {
      while (childFolders.hasNext()) { 
        var childFolder = childFolders.next();
        // Set permissions on the folder
        childFolder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);

        // Get the files in the child folder and loop
        var files = childFolder.getFiles();
        while (files.hasNext()) {

          files.next().setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);

         var viewEditors = schoolFolder.getEditors();

        // Loop the array of editors
          for (var j=0; j<viewEditors.length; j++) {
            email = viewEditors[j].getEmail();
            domain = viewEditors[j].getDomain();

            if (domain !== "testdomain.com") {
            // add as a viewer or remove completely?
              Logger.log("add " + email + " as a viewer");
              files.next().addViewer(email);
            } else {
              // Remove the editor
              Logger.log("removed " + email + " from folder");
              files.next().removeEditor(email);
            }
          };  
         }
       }

       };
      }    
        // Recursive call for any sub-folders
      //getChildFolders(childFolder);
 };
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I updated the script with your code I received the following error: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end." I've checked the files and it looks like their permissions were not updated. Do you have any insight as to why?

Comment: I updated to include the rest of the function, changing a couple things like irrelevant variable declarations. I haven't tested this in Drive.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I've tried running it a few different ways, but the code does not update the permissions correctly. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Lenny I think it has to do with the way you're handling nested folders. I just set up some dummy folders in my Drive. If the first folder you open via the spreadsheet ID doesn't have any children, the script moves on. I've added a conditional in the loop and updated the script above.